# Why i cant reset the form after getting the form's values ( vue.js / js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

im studing the Vue.js and i want to create some little application.
So i have a problem, **then i want to push new element to array using form values and after reset the form.
Problem is form doesnt reset**, but if i delete the line of pushing to array it's working. I know that javascript doesnt make the changes if opposites commands standing site by site but i've tried to solve that added `var WindowHeight = Window.innerHeight;"` between the commands but it still doesnt work.
Please can u help me, i dont know why its happening ? [HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iGBF.png) [Vue.js Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUwk1.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, in order to have a clear question format, it's better to include the code with it instead of external images. You can link a fiddle as well so people can test your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the form by resetting the reactive data after you have pushed the values:

```js
addnewProduct (e) {
    this.list.push({value1: this.value1, value2: this.value2})
    this.value1 = ""
    this.value2 = ""
}
```

Fully working example: [Vue SFC Playgorund](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Yes i can and its working if i use its only one comand, but using with other comand together, in my example  ```.push```  it doesnt work

Comment: @Kirill I see, that seems like I should. I have updated the answer. Set the reactive values to an empty string `""` after you have pushed it to the array

Comment: Yep, thx for your big help bro, its working now. You have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

`$event.target.reset` is a function. You need to execute it so add `()`:

```
$event.target.reset()
```

By the way:
`var WindowHeight = Window.innerHeight;` stores just a property of `Window` to `WindowHeight`, so this won't change anything on your page.

Comment: Its still not working, if i use only one command ```$event.target.reset()``` its working but if i use other comand  together, for example ```.push``` its stop working

Comment: @Kirill try to execute `$event.target.reset()` at first place of the function. So reset and then push.

Comment: Sorry but its still